# How should I save file directories in python so I won't encounter any problems if I switch to another OS?

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, sys

so for a long time I was a Windows guy so I just thought adding **backslashes** while writing directories in python for file manipulation would be okay. I however eventually found out that the UNIX systems use **slashes** instead and was dumbfounded for a while. That is to say until I discovered **os.path.join()**.

Alas now I have come across a most peculiar circumstance. I need to save a directory of a file into another file such that I can later retrieve it on another system. I'll handle this by splitting the directory string and saving it as a json, but I'm curious if there's a better approach. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the advantage of passing a _file path_ across systems?

Comment: Well you see I'm making a program which will be used by multiple users. The file path that is saved will actually be a relative path, in other words user A who owns a Windows might save it in a folder called "Kute Cittens" and user B who owns an Ubuntu might save it in a folder called  "Big Guy".

So user A's file location might be "C:\Kute Cittens\file.txt" and user B's file location might be "usr/local/bin/Big Guy/file.txt"

Comment: I think your easiest option would be to split and save, and then join.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was planning to go with

Comment: The alternative would be to store the source system's pathsep and then use `str.replace`.

Comment: Why not use a compression file format like `zip` or `tar gz`?

Comment: Perhaps I might consider that in the future. Not working with too big files just yet.